# How to find minimal polynominal of binary matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, polynomials

I am working in minimal polynominal of a binary matrix (1 or 0). I known some algorithm to find minimal polynominal of matrix such as Berlekamp Massey.  Could you suggest to me some matlab code to implement the Berlekamp Massey in Galios Field 2. I tried to use linbox lib but it take long time to complete and did not apply for binary matrix. This is my matrix

```
 A=[1     0     0    0; 
    0     1     0    1;
    1     1     1    1;
    1     1     1    0];
```

And this is my matlab code (But I think it is not suitable for my problem in GF(2))

```
function f=minPoly_Berlemap(A,b)
A=[1     0     0    0; 
    0     1     0    1;
    1     1     1    1;
    1     1     1    0];
b=[1;1;0;0];
[m n]=size(A);
A_u=[];
I=eye(n);
%% Step1
for i=1:(2*n)
    A_u(:,i)= mod(A^(i-1)*b,2);   
end
%% Step2
k=0;
g=[1];
gk=[1];
d=0;
%% Step3
while (d<n&k<n)
    %% Step4
    u_k=I(:,k+1);
    s=mod(u_k'*A_u,2);
    %% Step 5
    d = length(g)-1;
    mul_gs =mod( conv(g(end:-1:1),s),2); %multiply two polynomial
    s_g = mul_gs(d+1:end-d);  
    %% Step 6
    f=Berlekamp_Massey2(s_g);
    %% Step 7
    gk=mod(conv(f,g),2);    
    if d<n
        k=k+1;
        g=gk;
    else 
        break;
    end
end
    f=g
end
```

Comment: I guess you've considered minpol function for GF calculations, http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/minpol.html

Comment: I think your code should be pl = minpol(gf(M,1))

Comment: No, it has error Error using gf/minpol (line 20)
X must be a scalar or a column vector

Comment: @user8264: Any news about this?

Comment: @knedlsepp: To find minimal polynomal of a matrix, we can use Berlekamp-Massey. However, orignal Berlekamp-Massey only apply for sequence. To handle with problem, I read algorithm 2 of this paper http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/WIEDEMANN-IEEE-1986.pdf . Actually, it is not easy to implement. I am confusing the step 5 and 6 of that method. You can read this paper and let me know if you understand the step 5. Thanks

Comment: You didn't read the paper well enough. They are not applying the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix.

Comment: @knedlsepp: Yes, he applies for a sequence and that sequence can proceduced from a matrix. Finnaly, we can find the minimal polynomial of matrix via squences

Comment: @user8264: Maybe you can tell us some background information what you want to use this for. Maybe what you need for your solution is not actually the minimal polynomial of the matrix as a linear map, but something else. Maybe the minimal polynomial of the shift registers defined by the rows.

Comment: @user8264: As you say he applies it *for a sequence which was produced by a matrix*, which is not the same as *a matrix*. You wouldn't say you own a car-factory, when in fact you only own a car.

Comment: Yes, Maybe I use wrong word. For background, that I understand is that his goal is to find minimal polynomial of matrix. The traditional Berlekamp-Massey is only applied for sequence. So, To use it for matrix, he will try to build a sequence which created by inner production between unit vector u and Krylov space (step 4) . After that in step 5, he applied a polynomial to that sequence that produced in step 4. The output of step 5 is a sequence and we can use Berlekamp-Massey to find minimal polynomial.

Comment: Good, after reading a bit into the paper I agree that they use the BM-algorithm as important part for the calculation of the minimal polynomial of a matrix over a finite field. This paper describes what you need. You should read into it and start to implement the algorithm 2.

Comment: @knedlsepp: Do you understand step 5 of that paper? I will update my implementation for clear explaination

Answer (score 1):

### Problems with your code:

**Step 1:** Instead of `(A^i)*b` you should compute `A*(A*(...(A*b)..))`, as this has lower complexity. Replace:

```
%% Step1 - old
for i=1:(2*n)
    A_u(:,i)= mod(A^(i-1)*b,2);   
end
```

With this:

```
%% Step1 - new
A_u(:,1) = b;
for i = 2:2*n
    A_u(:,i) = mod(A*A_u(:,i-1), 2);   
end
```

### Original approach

Not reading too much into the problem I would suggest you the easy way out:

By just having a look at: `M, M^2, M^3, ...` we see, that

```
M^3 == eye(4)  [mod 2].
```

This way you know the degree of your polynomial is not larger than three. (As you could replace `M^4` with `M` and `M^5` with `M^2` and so on).

So your minimal polynomial must be one of those:

`a_0*eye(4) + a_1*M + a_2*M^2 + a_3*M^3`, with `a_i` in `{0,1}`.

You can simply try out all the `2^4-1 = 15` possibilites (we don't include the one where all a_i are zero) and you will see, that `M^3 - eye(4)` is your minimal polynomial.

Comment: I find that Berlekamp Massey method can find the coefficient of polynominal. Do you know how to apply it for my problem

Comment: Are you sure this can be done with the Berlekamp-Massey method? From reading the wikipedia page it seems to me, that it can find *the minimal polynomial of a linearly recurrent sequence*, which I'm not sure is the same thing as a minimal polynomial of a linear map. What do you need this for?